# Grails 1.4 vs. 2.0

Tags: grails, version, grails-2.0

Often I read Grails version 1.4 in forums and it looks Grails went from 1.3.7 to 2.0.  Was 1.4 the initial versioning plan and then they decided to call it 2.0?

Just curious...

Regards

Jonas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.
http://grails.org/blog/view/pledbrook/Grails+1.4+becomes+2.0